# PrimeFaces 5.2 Dialog Framework p:dialog widgetVar returns undefined

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, undefined, jsf-2.2

I am using Primefaces 5.2 for my web app. Despite searching internet for solutions and made lots of changes, I still couldn't be able to solve the problem and open the dialog component. After I've searched I added the followings in my web app:

```
<h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces"/>
```

to my JSF page header and the following to the faces-config.xml file.

```
<application>
    <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

When I try to open the dialog component I am getting the following error in the browser console:

```
Widget for var 'notifyDylg' not available!
mainPage.xhtml:356 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
```

The follow is my xhtml page content:

```
<h:form id="contentForm" styleClass="body">
<p:commandButton id="maxMapBtnId" value="#{general.maximizeMap}" icon="ui-icon-arrow-4-diag"
    type="button" onclick="PF('notifyDylg').show();">
</p:commandButton>

<p:dialog id="notifyDylgId" header="Notification" 
    widgetVar="notifyDylg" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="blind" closeOnEscape="true">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.notifyMessage}" />          
</p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Anybody help for the case above?

Comment: Your code is not an mcve so it is impossible to see where you call things from.

Comment: What did you mean, I coundn't understan your point. Should I give more information about the problem?

Comment: Read [ask] and in there the part about an mcve. Also check the jsf info page on stackoverflow about an mcve.